# How to increase speed of mousemove/clientX/Y and applying a transform?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, addeventlistener, mousemove

I have built a WordPress theme. I came across a website that created a div to follow the user's cursor. The div was enlarged smoothly when the user hovers over a button or a link.

I want to add this nice functionality as an optional feature.

I added a div to the web page, `#ambition_cursor` and added some basic styling. The div now shows like a blue circle. The circle has position fixed to the top left corner of the site. The position can be changed by adding a CSS `translate` property.

I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
var ambition_cursor =  document.getElementById("ambition_cursor");

function ambition_mouse(e) {

    var ambition_cursor_x = e.clientX;     // Get the horizontal coordinate
    var ambition_cursor_y = e.clientY;     // Get the vertical coordinate 

    var ambition_cursor_pos = `translate(${ambition_cursor_x}px, ${ambition_cursor_y}px)`;
    ambition_cursor.style.transform = ambition_cursor_pos;
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', ambition_mouse);
```

The big downside here is the lag (?). There's quite a big delay, especially when moving the mouse around very fast. You can try it out [on this site](https://ambitionthemes.com/preview/). I also put the situation in [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ralphsmit/becw5f2g/3/); although the delay doesn't really happen there.

I didn't apply yet much styling (the default cursor is visible, so you can get a better idea of the real position). I first want this to work better, before I spent much time on that.

How can I increase the speed of this, so that the div position follows the mouse more accurately? I'm a beginner, so I don't really know which JavaScript optimisations I should make.

Current code is JavaScript, but jQuery is also an option.

Many thanks in advance!

Update: [example how it looks on my computer.](https://ambitionthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Mousemove_Delay.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements on the page have a transition applied. Remove/override this style and the delay goes away (tested).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the great answer of Joseph Atkinson:

```
var ambition_cursor =  document.getElementById("ambition_cursor");

    function ambition_mouse(e) {
    
        ambition_cursor.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';     // Get the horizontal coordinate
        ambition_cursor.style.top = e.clientY + 'px' ;     // Get the vertical coordinate 
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', ambition_mouse);
```

See: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/use-javascript-to-make-an-element-follow-the-cursor-3872307778b4

Answer (score 0):

I visited the site example, cracked open the dev console, and found ***throttled(20, ambition_mouse)*** It is not a performance issue, and the solution is to not throttle the events. It was too smooth to be a performance issue, which gave me the first clue it had to be an accidental/deliberate effect.

[image]

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for checking it out! I added throttling later, as a possible solution and, because I thought it smoother than without, I left it there. I now removed the throttling, but unfortunately it still persists.. would you mind having a look again?

Comment: In your JSFiddle the dot follows the cursor without (almost) a delay. You don't want that?

Comment: Hi @Karlan, yes that's what I want. But the problem is that the dot does have a delay on a bigger web page, like ambitionthemes.com/preview. I added a link to a GIF in the question how it looks on my computer..

Comment: @ralphsmit ek, sorry. Should have tested. Famous last words of any software engineer. 
When face with a bug it does help to remove all variables that could affect it, would of speed up my debugging. Prevented me from bad habits like assuming. Help me help you if your picking up what I'm putting down.

Comment: No problem, can imagine that it's a bit more difficult to debug code you've not written yourself ;-) Anyway, thanks for your fast help!